# Intializing and setting up values in ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory

How Can I set values of variables in ADF ,In set variable activity I can only set one variable's values if there is 10 variables I need to set 10 set variable activities, Is there any other ways to minimize this effort

Comment: Hi, Can you please provide your sample source and expected output?

Comment: Hi @NiharikaMoola-MT ,sure                                                                                              Array o/p ->{x:ab,y:cd,z:ef}{x:fg,y:hg,z:jh},I want to set the values of x ,y and z in a foreach loop,  for that i used 3 set variable property .

Answer (score 1):

You can use Append Variable activity to append the new value to the existing variable.

- Create an array type variable.

[image]

- Add append variable activity inside ForEach activity to add value to a variable for every iteration.

[image]